# Conversion of an Adobe PDF to the JPEG

Tags: php, pdf

Is there any ready PHP-based soultiuon for creation of an JPEG images from the Adobe's PDF files? Just like this: http://www.convertpdftoimage.com/

Answer (score 3):

The [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) program allows conversion between graphic formats, and it includes support for reading PDF files. Therefore it should be able to convert PDF to JPG. (indeed, googling for [ImageMagick pdf to jpg](http://www.google.com/search?q=imagemagick+pdf+to+jpg) gives plenty of results, with good usage examples)

Furthermore, there is a [PHP extension for ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), so if you have that extension included in your PHP, then it should be pretty simple (you can check which extensions are included in a given PHP installation by using the `phpinfo()` function).

If you don't have that extension (and you can't install it), you can still use ImageMagick, using it's command-line interface via the PHP `shell_exec()` function, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about PHP. But we use this application: [Callas pdfToolbox](http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en%3aproducts%3apdftoolbox4). It's standalone on your UNIX server.
Apache provides a Java solutions: [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Not sure PHP is capable of rendering PDF's. Getting the text out of then however should be easy.